# Laravel 6 send mail

Tags: laravel, email, authentication

I have an issue with authentication while sending mail with Laravel smtp driver.

`.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=account@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=account@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=app_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

It gives the following error:

> "530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. "

- 2-Factor auth is enabled and app password is used;
- Also tried with SSL on 465, same error;
- Config is flushed every time .env is changed;
- Everything in config/mail corresponds to .env;

SO all typical solutions are not working. What else may cause this problem?

I have also tried using smtp.vivaldi.net with vivaldi account, it authenticates, but gives an error:

> "no valid recipients"

while recipient email is surely valid, which is also strange for me.

Comment: you checked the data in your services.php file?

Comment: @LucasPiazzi i'm using default smtp driver, so there's blank templates for other drivers only in this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I messed up with `config/mail.php`.

I wrote

`'username' => env('email'), 
'password' => env('app_password'),`

Instead of

`'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','email'), 
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','app_password'),`

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled across this multiple times already, hence I do not remember the exact error-message which I received but here is my assumption.

Google has an option called "less secure apps" which you need to enable in order to send directly mails through their SMTP interface. Can you check if this flag is disabled and try to enable it?

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879

In addition to that google is slowly deprecating this feature. Starting from Mid 2020 you'll be not able to enable this flag anymore and they will completely remove this in 2021.

Reference: https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/12/less-secure-apps-oauth-google-username-password-incorrect.html

Comment: @hardnight mh.. strange. Everything else seems good to me. Did you checked that you didn't used the wrong port + encryption combination? This is the only thing which seems incorrect in your .env example... SSL = 465, TLS = 587. I also mix them up all the time ;-)

Comment: @hardnight another thing which I realise right now. There is different ways of enabling "less secure apps". You can enable it for the whole G Suite or on a per-account basis. Can you verify both cases?

Comment: @hardnight are you still experiencing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to setup 2 step verification here [google security](https://myaccount.google.com/security). 
An App Password link will appear and you can get your App Password to insert into below "MAIL_PASSWORD". More info on getting App Password [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@talhaf.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=System
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=YOUR_GMAIL@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=YOUR_GMAIL_CREATED_APP_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Don't forget to clear cache with :

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: It's stated in question that it's already done and still not working

Comment: `no valid recipients` means your `$mail->to` email is incorrect